# Adaptive Cards Support for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have integrated a the MSFT chatbot with Teams, i am able to connect and interact, however for response that are based on Adaptive Cards, i get the below error "The specified card version is not supported."

Any idea when the adaptive cards be supported with MSFT teams.

Environment: 
Adaptive Cards v 0.5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive cards are now supported in Microsoft Teams (on desktop and web).

A couple of things to note:

- You're using the old version of the nuget package. Please use this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/ (v1.0.3 is the currently the latest version)
- Check the attachment content you're sending in your request, and make sure it's an adaptive card (instance of `AdaptiveCard`) w/ version = 1.0. `Attachment.Content` is of type object, so it's easy to accidentally put other things in there--in my case an `AdaptiveCardParseResult`, oops! :)

Comment: Thank you will the new package.

Comment: are newer versions supported? I want to use v1.1 to embed videos, but cant get it to work.