# Microsoft Bot Framework - Adaptive card version not supported in Teams and Skype for Business

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have created a bot and deployed it to Azure. In the Azure portal, I have configured Skype for business and Microsoft Teams as channels for my bot.
The bot is using Adaptive Cards to show details of entities, the user has entered (to create a meeting).

I have tested the bot with Bot Framework Emulator using the Azure URL of the bot. Everyting works as expected.
- Entities are properly resolved with LUIS
- Details are filled in the Adaptive Card
- The Adaptive Card is showing in the chat window.

Not so for Skype for Business and Microsoft Teams.
Nothing at all is showing in Skype for Business.

In Microsoft Teams, I receive an error message "The specified card version is not supported.".
I am using the latest NuGet Packages for BotBuilder - Version 3.16 at this point of time. Anyway, the problem exists.

I'd expect, Adaptive Cards code would be compatible with all Microsoft products.
What can I do, to get my Adaptive Cards working in Teams, Skype for Business... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of the AdaptiveCards package are you using?  I had this same issue after support was announced for Microsoft Teams, but I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792512/adaptive-cards-support-for-microsoft-teams) which directed me to update my [AdaptiveCards package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/).  Since updating, my AdaptiveCards work in Teams.

Comment: You made my day... Like mentioned in the article, I had Microsoft.AdaptiveCards 0.5.1 only in my project. After installing the AdaptiveCards 1.0.3 package cards show in Teams. Works like a charm....

Answer (score 0):

Franz,
Team's support for adaptive cards is still in Preview and Skype is still in development according to the Adaptive Card partner status page located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners).

The announcement of Adaptive Cards for Teams was recently made but was premature according to comments on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#cards-supported-in-teams) site.

I'm eagerly awaiting this feature to go live myself. It does appear, at least for Teams, to be coming very, very soon.

David's reply below is correct! If you update to the latest Nuget package (1.0.3) Adaptive Cards will work in Teams. Hooray! No Skype support yet.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I'll consider that in my developments.